# xcode 4 editing multiple targets duplicates changes

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4

I have a project setup with two separate projects in two separate schemes, the only difference between the two targets is that they have different bundle ids and different icons.  However whenever I change the second target and build it the changes are copied to the first target.  I'm not sure what's going on, the only thing I could think of is they have the same product name so the app executable name is the same.  Does someone know if this is causing it and if so how could i fix, or is something else going on?

Thanks

Comment: I update the project to use different product name for the different targets and still the same, thing, when I update one target build and highlight the other target the icon and bundle id are changed. This is very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that in your new target have you specified a new plist file 
and that the target points to this plist file and as you pointed out you also changed the product name in the build settings, the only thing I can think of at this point is that your schemes are both pointing to the same executable. Open both schemes in the scheme editor and look at what the executable field is pointing to. They may both be pointing to the same thing.

Comment: Can two targets in the same project have the same executable name?  I think that's how my project is setup right now?  That may be the problem.

Comment: yes, you can set multiple targets to point to a single XXX.app file under "Edit Schemes". I don't do this and wouldn't unless I was doing an A/B comparison

Comment: You were right, I was really screwed up in how I was building the targets. First they both pointed to the same plist which caused the duplication.  Additionally the both build the same executable, which I fixed by changing the product names and just setting the bundle display name to update the app icon title.  Thanks for the help.